# Using hidden fields for updating data in database

Tags: php, html, forms, crud

So I have a html table containing data retrieved from the database. In each row, there is an "edit" button. It looks like this:

```
<td><form action="controller/edit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="edit">
</form></td>
```

Then in the controller/edit page I will access the database again:

```
select * from table where id=$_POST['id']
```

This is all fine. However I am thinnking of avoiding the second access to the database to improve performance. I am trying to do something like this:

```
<td><form action="controller/edit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="edit">
</form></td>
```

This way all the data from the row is in the form, so when the form submits to controller/edit I don't need to access the database again. Is this approach fine? Or Is this bad practice?

Comment: For something infrequent like an edit interface? just load it again from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one you've mentioned does seem like a shortcut, but it can be vulnerable.

Hidden fields can easily be tampered. For example, a user can manipulate the value of the hidden field and change the value to a random number like 975646456456456.

In that case, your database will have an incorrect insertion since there probably wouldn't be a matching record corresponding to id  975646456456456.

So, I think you should go with the first one and check your database if the id exists, and fetch its records.

Answer (score -1):

Try to submit using `jquery.button`. For example submit form:

```
submitform(){
        jQuery('form id').attr('action','url'+'?id= "id from db");
        jQuery('form id').submit();
}
```